# How to modify title for failed jasmine tests to include separator after each describe title?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

If a jasmine test fails, the header for the failed test contains all sub headers of the `describe` and `it` methods, e.g. for

```
describe('foo', function(){
  describe('baa', function(){
    it('qux', function(){
      expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

the header line becomes

```
foo baa qux
```

[image]

In order to be able to easier read the header, I would like to add a separator after the individual describe titles. With

```
describe('foo / ', function(){
  describe('baa / ', function(){
    it('qux', function(){
      expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

the header line becomes

```
foo / baa / qux
```

However, I do not want to manually add the separator for each `describe`.

=>How to tell jasmine (or jasmine-html reporter?) to automatically insert a separator after each `describe` title?

Comment: Maybe you could try wrapping it in karma and using something like karma-spec-reporter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I override the describe function to add the separator to the title:

```
function addSeparatorAfterDescribeTitlesToImproveHeaderForFailedTests() {
    var describeSeparator = ' / ';

    if(!window.jasmineHasBeenCustomized) {
      var oldDescribe = window.describe;
      window.describe = function (description, specDefinitions) {
        oldDescribe(description + describeSeparator, specDefinitions);
      };
      window.jasmineHasBeenCustomized = true;
    }

  }
```

I call this method in customMatchers.js, where I already define my custom matchers for jasmine.